# Enumeration with specific type and property

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I want validate if an Animal is a Person and its name is Alex.

Person object:

```
type Person(name: string) =
        member this.Name = name
```

Enumration:

```
type Animal =
| Person of Person
| Cat
| Dog
```

Pattern matching:

```
let KnowAnimal animal =
    match animal with
    | Person person && person.Name = "Alex" -> 1
    | Cat -> 2
    | Dog -> 3
    | _ -> 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify pattern guards with `when`:

```
let KnowAnimal animal =
    match animal with
    | Person person when person.Name = "Alex" -> 1
    | Cat -> 2
    | Dog -> 3
    | _ -> 4
```